# R / tibble - subset time series up to variable condition met?

Tags: r, time-series, tidyverse, tibble

How do I subset a time series from the start up to the first occurrence of a variable meeting a condition?

```
tribble(
  ~t, ~x, ~y,
  as.POSIXct(strptime("2011-03-27 01:30:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")), -1, 1,
  as.POSIXct(strptime("2011-03-27 01:30:01", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")), -5, 2,
  as.POSIXct(strptime("2011-03-27 03:45:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")), -3, 5,
  as.POSIXct(strptime("2011-03-27 04:20:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")), -8, 3,
  as.POSIXct(strptime("2011-03-27 04:25:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")), -2, 8
)
```

For example all rows from start to first occurrence of `y > 4` (expecting the first three rows of the sample data).

***h3rm4ns Solution explained***

simpler case of not including the first row to match the condition would be:

```
 %>% filter(cumsum(y > 4) == 0)
```

`y > 4` will be false which is equal to `0` in R, so the `cumsum == 0` will return `TRUE` (and thus filter) for all rows up to the first one that matches `y > 4` and therefore adds a  `1` to the sum.

To have it include the matching row, we additionally `lag(y, default = 0)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
df %>% filter(!cumsum(lag(y, default = 0) > 4))
```

The result:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
                    t     x     y
               <dttm> <dbl> <dbl>
1 2011-03-27 01:30:00    -1     1
2 2011-03-27 01:30:01    -5     2
3 2011-03-27 03:45:00    -3     5
```